# Apps are looking for $HOME, literally

Tags: home-directory, environment-variables

After a power outage my user settings appeared to have vanished. However, my home folder was apparently fine, except that there was a new folder called `$HOME` in there.

After some fiddling I noticed some apps where storing settings in there. I erased them and made `$HOME` a symlink to my home folder. Re-logging in I noticed that brought back most of my desktop, except that one or other minor apps is misbehaving. Namely, there's a unnamed (aha!) error dialog stating that `It wasn't possible to create the data directory "$HOME/.config/mate/mate-dictionary": permission denied`.

How can I track down what's making apps look for the literal `$HOME`?

*Running Linux Mint 16, based on Ubuntu 12.04, on MATE*

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure on how this got "off-topic", as Mint is as Ubuntu as Kubuntu would be. This is not an issue with the Mint system itself, but with something as generic as a environment variable and user dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **auditd** to look for the app accessing `$HOME`

```
sudo apt-get install auditd
```

then add a rule to monitor access to $HOME

```
sudo auditctl -w /home/<username>/$HOME -k whoaccesshome
```

That might need some tweaking as I write it down from memory.

then, look for a match with

```
sudo ausearch -k whoaccesshome
```

You will get the *pid* of the running process to help you troubleshoot your problem

Note: this will not survive a reboot. To make the rule permanent, change `/etc/auditd/rules.d/audit.rules`

Comment: will give this a shot!